# wrap a c library in cython which includes a python internal c symbol

Tags: c, cython

So I'm working on an interface between Ox and Python. The issue is this: Ox defines a function `c_pow`, which Cython 'mangles' to `_Py_c_pow`. Unfortunately this function is [allready defined](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/complex.html#c.Py_complex). Is there a way to prevent a naming conflict in this situation? Can I specify my own prefix for example?

```
#"jdmath.h"
...
void   JDCALL c_pow(double xr, double xi, double a, double *yr, double *yi);
...

#"oxcy.pxd"
cdef extern from r'dev\jdmath.h':
    pass
```

Compiler output:

```
PS D:\Git\OxPy\oxcy> python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning oxcy.pyx to oxcy.c
building 'oxcy' extension
    ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\OxMetrics7\ox\bin" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\OxMetrics7\ox\dev\lib64" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\OxMetrics7\ox\dev" -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC /Tcoxcy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\oxcy.obj
oxcy.c
d:\git\oxpy\oxcy\dev\jdmath.h(111) : warning C4031: second formal parameter list longer than the first list
d:\git\oxpy\oxcy\dev\jdmath.h(111) : warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration
d:\git\oxpy\oxcy\dev\jdmath.h(111) : warning C4273: '_Py_c_abs' : inconsistent dll linkage
    c:\anaconda2\include\complexobject.h(30) : see previous definition of '_Py_c_abs'
d:\git\oxpy\oxcy\dev\jdmath.h(117) : warning C4031: second formal parameter list longer than the first list
d:\git\oxpy\oxcy\dev\jdmath.h(117) : warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration
d:\git\oxpy\oxcy\dev\jdmath.h(117) : warning C4028: formal parameter 2 different from declaration
d:\git\oxpy\oxcy\dev\jdmath.h(117) : error C2371: '_Py_c_pow' : redefinition; different basic types
    c:\anaconda2\include\complexobject.h(29) : see declaration of '_Py_c_pow'
error: command '~\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

### Edit

It turns out that Anaconda defines a macro: `#define c_pow _Py_c_pow`. So, although Cython is not to blame for the mangling, compilation still fails on a name collision caused by the macro in a Python C header and a header from Ox. How can I circumvent this issue?

Comment: Cython doesn't mangle the names of anything specified in a `cdef extern from ...` block - it just includes the header file. Your problem is caused by something else.

Comment: In that case, can you comment on why the thrown error references the line in `jdmath.h` that defines `c_pow`, stating that `_Py_c_pow` is redefined there? -EDIT- I found a macro in `complexobject.h` that does the redefinition. The problem persists though.

Comment: Ah yes - that makes more sense... (Dunno how to fix it immediately though)

Comment: One thing to know is that this is specifically a Python 2 bug. Python 3 looks to just define `_Py_c_pow`

Comment: Thank you for verifying that, I will definitely (once more) nudge management towards an upgrade.

Comment: I think I have an (OKish) solution... I'm just writing it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, this is caused by [macros defined by Python 2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/complexobject.h#L21) causing the renaming. They aren't defined in Python 3, so one option is to upgrade.

Assuming you don't want to upgrade (which is probably reasonable...) then it's trickier. The easiest thing to try is just to add

```
#undef c_pow
#undef c_abs
```

to the top of jdmath.h. (Alternatively, if you can't modify jdmath.h then create a new header, that undefines the macros and includes jdmath.h then use that new header from Cython).

Hopefully this will work fine. It's possible however that this will break something in Cython (you'll get an obvious compile error) if it attempts to use the Python defined `c_pow` and `c_abs` itself. In this case you want to create a header that creates functions with new names:

```
// undefine so we can access c_pow and c_abs
#undef c_pow
#undef c_abs

#include "dev/jdmath.h"

inline void not_c_pow(/* fill in args yourself*/) { c_pow(/*args*/); }
inline void not_c_abs(/* fill in args yourself*/) { c_abs(/*args*/); }

// redefine to original state
#define c_pow _Py_c_pow
#define c_abs _Py_c_abs
```

In Cython you'd use `not_c_pow` and `not_c_abs` instead and it should work.